# How to add angular builder/custom webpack for different environment?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server, angular-builder

Currently I am using the custom builder for "serve" in angular.json file, like this

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:qa"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:local"
            },
}
```

I have tried to add builder option inside "local" also, but it is not working
, so Is there any way to add this builder for "serve local" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it directly under `architect` > `build` to be enabled for all environments:

```json
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
        "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path": "./webpack.config.js",
                "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
         ....
```